# Access to sql Fiware

Tags: mysql, sql, fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-wirecloud

I have a problem with SQL access from the fiwarelab machine.
I have to duplicate the same as in fiwarelab in local, by code I have designed a graph to show the SQL data.

As I said in local if I work correctly, but when I make the query to the machine of fiwarelab I can not show the graphs, nor the errors that I have programmed for a bad connection.

I'm somewhat lost with the fiwarelab theme

Do I have to open the ports or change some configuration of SQL?

Good again

I have managed to activate the PHP log and now it gives me this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/graficas/pruebas.php on line 3

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ual");


if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    $data_points = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ual_iot"); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $point = array("valorx" => $row['valor'], "valory" => $row['tiempo']);
        array_push($data_points, $point);
    }
    echo json_encode($data_points);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is my test file in case any configuration fails and this is the connection.

Comment: How do you send the query to your VM on FIWARE Lab? In any case, go to _Security_ -> _Security Groups_, select the security group your VM belongs to and then select _Edit Rules_ from the action drop-down on the right. On the pop-up window, check if you have a rule for the port through which you are trying to communicate with your VM.

Comment: So... your problem has nothing to do with FIWARE itself, but with a missing module. Do you need details about how to install the msyql module for php?

Comment: Good,

Thanks for the help. I have already solved the problem, I was missing to install some packages and Mysql and php.

a greeting